# sublimerepl getenv failing

Tags: clojure, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'd like to use the SiblimeREPL package with Sublime Text.  When I try to start a REPL, I get

```
SublimeREPL: obtaining sane environment failed in getenv()
Check console and 'getenv_command' setting
WARN: Falling back to SublimeText environment
```

This happens regardless of which REPL I try to start.  (I tried Ruby, Python, and Clojure.)  I tried Sublime Text 2 and Sublime Text 3 with the same results.  This is on Mac OS X, if that matters.

I looked in the package settings, where I see

```
"getenv_command": ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c", "env"],
```

If I run "/bin/bash --login -c env" at a Terminal prompt, I get my environment listed.

What do I need to change in order to get a successful getenv_command?

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem as ssgam. The problem line for me is in the getenv method. It calls **subprocess.check_output(getenv_command)**, which doesn't exist in python 2.6, which ST2 seems to use.

The trick is, it only calls subprocess.check_output() if getenv_command is truthy, and defaults to os.environ.copy() otherwise. So to get ssgam's fix without modifying the SublimeREPL package, in **Preferences > Package Settings > SublimeREPL > Settings - User**, do something like this:

```
{
  "getenv_command": false
}
```

Comment: I don't know about side effects but this did eliminate the error message in my case (Sublime 2 + Fedora 23)

Comment: Fixed for Python, my Node is still not working though. This solution is still worth a +1 .

Comment: Removes the error, thanks! But what are the side effects of doing this?

Comment: Looks like os.environ is only initialized once, so it won't pick up environmental changes after ST starts (probably):
https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#process-parameters

Other than that, I don't know. The default value specifically looks in your environment from Bash, so maybe that could be different. It could probably mean that some env variable you wanted to set might not be picked up unless you set it in the correct environment settings file. I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Comment: I favor the answer by @ParthThakkar below because it gets more to the root of the problem and bypasses most/all potential side effect issues: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38036933/3541976

Comment: Well, that solution modifies sublime package code... so usually not good practice. If you submit that solution as a bug to the appropriate place, that'd be helpful. I mainly prefer my solution because it's just a settings change that has no feasible side effects (it doesn't "disable a whole part of the config", it uses a different code path for finding the environment).

Answer (score 6):

I investigated this issue a little bit deeper and it seems SublimeText 3 is also affected. In my case the problem is related to bash-completion feature, in particular COMP_WORDBREAKS environment variable.

Use the following command to show the contents of COMP_WORDBREAKS:

```
$ echo "$COMP_WORDBREAKS"
```

will output

```
"'><=;|&(:
```

You can also use:

```
$ echo $COMP_WORDBREAKS
```

but note that with the second command (without quotes), you'll not see that
the variable also contains a line feed character.

The problem here is the line feed character which breaks output parsing in getenv_command feature. If you extract part of the source code for SublimeREPL you can get real error message from python interpreter.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 71, in getenv
    env = dict(line.split('=', 1)  for line in lines)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #6 has length 1; 2 is required
```

You can match element #6 with the position of COMP_WORDBREAKS in env listing.

**Solution (first that came to my mind)**

I can't tell at the moment what is real impact on bash-completion feature after following solution is applied and of course SublimeREPL hopefully  should be fixed accordingly. Please comment my answer to fill in missing knowledge.

We may want to remove disturbing characters to get rid of the error.
First let's identify those characters

```
$ echo -n "${COMP_WORDBREAKS}" | od -t x1c
```

will output

```
0000000  20  09  0a  22  27  3e  3c  3b  7c  26  28  3a
             \t  \n   "   '   >   <   ;   |   &   (   :
0000014
```

so we have three to remove. The simplest way is to add to your ***.bashrc*** following line:

```
COMP_WORDBREAKS="${COMP_WORDBREAKS#???}"
```

Voila! No more error message.

My final thought is about removed characters. I'm not fully in how bash-completion works and I'm aware of that modifying COMP_WORDBREAKS can affect other scripts using it. For now you can always change it ad-hoc.

I hope this helped.

Cheers

Comment: The description of your investigation helped me solve mine! I didn't have the COMP_WORDBREAKS issue (for some reason it doesn't get displayed in the list produced by env, but echo $COMP_WORDBREAKS does show its value). The problem in my case was the login shell showed a greeting before displaying the environment variables. So I just removed the --login argument from sublime config's getenv_command and that solved it!

Comment: @ParthThakkar Post this as an answer! I first followed the first answer of completely making getenv false, but I felt a little worried as that was setting a whole part of the config to false, and I don't know what that does or what potential side effects are. Then I looked at your comment, and, realizing that I have a bash terminal greeting too, it may be the problem! So I just removed the --login argument, and it's working!

Comment: @Rohan, I did remove it for a while, and I think it did work, but I felt a bit uneasy about it because of the comment in the SublimeREPL.sublime-settings file (the one above the getenv_command setting). So I later went to the line of code that was causing the problem (I can't recall which file it was in - but the above answer says: 'File "main.py", line 71, in getenv
    env = dict(line.split('=', 1)  for line in lines)'.

So, I went to that line and modified the code - to split the line only if it has an `=` sign, and ignore it otherwise. I added the --login argument back.

Comment: And I can't post an answer right now, I don't remember the file that was causing the problems. If you find it, you can post! :)

Comment: @ParthThakkar I have no clue which file it is in, could you try finding it again?

Comment: @Rohan, I found the code to be in ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/SublimeREPL/repls/subprocess_repl.py and all I did was to replace the problematic line `env = dict(line.split('=', 1)  for line in lines)` with `env = dict(line.split('=', 1)  for line in filter( lambda line: line.find("=") > 0, lines))`

Comment: @ParthThakkar I was too lazy to open the file, locate the line, and change the code. And I was also bit skeptical of changing the source code without knowing what the side effects are. But I found a better solution! I made it so my terminal greets me ONLY when it detects it is in an interactive session. So, I used the syntax `if [[ $- == *i* ]]
then
    #Greeting

Comment: Your solution worked for me, but the bash shell autocompletions stopped working after the modification, so I had to revert it at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Found it.  Fixed it. SublimeREPL assumes that running getenv_command will produce SOLELY the output from running env, and every line will contain an equals sign.  But my .bash_profile echos some stuff to stdout.

The solution was to wrap my .bash_profile output in a

```
if [[ $- == *i* ]]
```

to not produce extra output besides the executed command.

Answer (score 3):

## TLDR;

Replace:

```
env = dict(line.split('=', 1)  for line in lines)
```

in `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/SublimeREPL/repls/subprocess_repl.py` with

```
env = dict(line.split('=', 1)  for line in lines if '=' in line)
```

(Thanks @MichaelOhlrogge for the shorter syntax)

---

## Why this works

@develucas's solution helped me solve my issue. I didn't have the problem he was describing, but his investigation helped.

In my case, the login shell had a greeting. So, `bash --login -c env` (the command specified in `SublimeREPL.sublime-settings` file under the `getenv_command` option) was printing something like this:

```
Hello, parth!
USER=parth
SHELL=/bin/bash
.
.
.
```

It turns out that SublimeREPL uses the output of this command to load the environment variables - as mentioned in the comment above the `getenv_command` setting:

```
// On POSIX system SublimeText launched from GUI does not inherit
// a proper environment. Often leading to problems with finding interpreters
// or not using the ones affected by changes in ~/.profile / *rc files
// This command is used as a workaround, it's launched before any subprocess
// repl starts and it's output is parsed as an environment
"getenv_command": ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c", "env"],
```

The code that parses this output is like this (in the `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/SublimeREPL/repls/subprocess_repl.py` file for ST3):

```
def getenv(self, settings):
    """Tries to get most appropriate environent, on windows
       it's os.environ.copy, but on other system's we'll
       try get values from login shell"""

    getenv_command = settings.get("getenv_command")
    if getenv_command and POSIX:
        try:
            output = subprocess.check_output(getenv_command)
            lines = output.decode("utf-8", errors="replace").splitlines()
            env = dict(line.split('=', 1)  for line in lines)
            return env
        except:
            import traceback
            traceback.print_exc()
            error_message(
                "SublimeREPL: obtaining sane environment failed in getenv()\n"
                "Check console and 'getenv_command' setting \n"
                "WARN: Falling back to SublimeText environment")

    # Fallback to environ.copy() if not on POSIX or sane getenv failed
    return os.environ.copy()
```

The `env = dict(line.split('=', 1)  for line in lines)` line causes an issue, because the first line in the `bash --login -c env` output has no `=`. So I modified this line to ignore the lines that don't have an `=` sign:

`env = dict(line.split('=', 1)  for line in lines if '=' in line)`

And this solved the issue for me. Don't forget the restart Sublime Text after modifying this file.

Comment: Nice! This seems preferable to a lot of the other answers since it gets closer to the root of the issue with a minimum of potential side effects!

Comment: I used a slightly more minimal syntax, changing `for line in lines` to `for line in lines if "=" in line`.

Answer (score 1):

changing COMP_WORDBREAKS does not work for me ...
i'm using ST2, and the exception was thrown at check_output().

also, name completions at the command line fails, after changing COMP_WORDBREAKS.

in my case, i changed subprocess_repl.py's env() method:

```
[wind]$ diff subprocess_repl.py.20151117.173317 subprocess_repl.py
160c160,161
<         updated_env = env if env else self.getenv(settings)
---
>         # updated_env = env if env else self.getenv(settings)
>         updated_env = env if env else os.environ.copy()
[wind]$
```

would be interesting to find out why the problem started appearing suddenly ...

hth,cheers,

sam

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @develucas mostly works for me with ST3 with OSX El Capitan except I had to put

`export COMP_WORDBREAKS="${COMP_WORDBREAKS#???}"`

Note the export. However, if I do this, tab completion no longer works.

Comment: I submitted a PR that fixes the problem for me. Perhaps you can give it try? https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/pull/458

Comment: Thanks a lot! its works for me for Fedora 23 and python 3

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it was my `.bash_profile` that had some utility outputs, such as a welcome message etc.

These outputs are parsed by SublimeREPL to try to extract environment variables from the output of the `env` command, and the extraneous text lines mixed together provoked the error.

(I'd like to make a PR to SublimeREPL to try to make that phase more robust, it should not depend on particular `.bash_profile` implementations!)