# Using sublime text2 in Mac for python

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I'm the new user in Mac.I'm trying to use python in the Mac. So, I use the sublime text 2 for this.

I use sublimeREPL:python to run python. but I think that I have some problems.

First of all, the version of Python is different in the terminal OS X and sublime text2.

In terminal,

```
Python 2.7.11 (default, Feb 27 2016, 16:44:31) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

In sublime text,

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 18:05:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Also, when I use the sublimeREPL:python, I got an error message like below.

```
SublimeREPL: obtaining sane environment failed in getenv()
Check console and 'getenv_command' setting 
WARN: Falling back to SublimeText environment
```

I think that this is kind of path problem in Windows. but I have no idea how to fix it. My Mac OS X El Capitan version is 10.11.3.

Please, give me an advice.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT.**

I add the SublimeText console (View|Console) message when I ran the sublimeREPL:python.

```
startup, version: 2221 osx x64 channel: stable
executable: /Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime Text 2
working dir: /
packages path: /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages
settings path: /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Settings
PackageSetup not required
catalogue loaded
found 6 files for base name Default.sublime-keymap
found 1 files for base name Default.sublime-mousemap
found 38 files for base name Main.sublime-menu
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/0_package_control_loader/00-package_control.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/0_package_control_loader/02-bz2.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/CSS/css_completions.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/comment.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/copy_path.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/delete_word.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/detect_indentation.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/duplicate_line.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/echo.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/exec.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/fold.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/font.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/goto_line.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/indentation.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/kill_ring.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/mark.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/new_templates.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/open_file_settings.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/open_in_browser.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/paragraph.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/save_on_focus_lost.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/scroll.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/set_unsaved_view_name.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/side_bar.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/sort.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/swap_line.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/switch_file.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/transform.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/transpose.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/trim_trailing_white_space.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Diff/diff.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/HTML/encode_html_entities.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/HTML/html_completions.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Package Control/1_reloader.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Package Control/2_bootstrap.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Package Control/Package Control.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/SublimeREPL/__init__.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/SublimeREPL/completions.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/SublimeREPL/lang_integration.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/SublimeREPL/run_existing_command.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/SublimeREPL/sublimerepl.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/SublimeREPL/sublimerepl_build_system_hack.py
Reloading plugin /Users/kims/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/SublimeREPL/text_transfer.py
plugin init time: 1.25108
loading bindings
loading pointer bindings
found 1 files for base name Default.sublime-theme
theme loaded
app ready
pre session restore time: 1.75546
using gamma: 1.9 (err: 99.6544)
startup cache, total files: 170 cache hits: 170
startup time: 1.9001 (package setup was not run)
loaded 837 snippets
Package Control: No updated packages
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./repls/subprocess_repl.py", line 144, in getenv
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output'
error: SublimeREPL: obtaining sane environment failed in getenv()
Check console and 'getenv_command' setting 
WARN: Falling back to SublimeText environment
```

Comment: Can you open the SublimeText console (**View|Console**) and find the exception that should be printed there when SublimeREPL launches?

Comment: I add the message when I launched the SublimeREPL.

Comment: Seems to be a [known bug](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/issues/342). There's [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34014231/274466) trick you could try. You may also want to change the `"default_extend_env"` (in your `SublimeREPL.sublime-settings`) to `"{PATH}:/usr/local/bin"` so it picks up on the Python you have installed there (I assume homebrew?)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You shouldn't be using the Python interpreter that is bundled with `Sublime` to run your code. It is used for running packages (i.e. plugins for Sublime text).</strike>

If you want to test something quick inside a REPL, just run `python` in a shell and start hacking.

SublimeREPL uses python with `virutalenv`, so you need to create one that uses the `python` interpreter you'd like:

```
virtualenv -p /path/to/python path-to-virtualenv
```

To see which is your default python, run

```
which python
```

After you've created your virutalenv, you need to make sure the package is using it by adding this to your package settings (choose `Preferences: SublimeREPL (User)` from the command palette) and enter:

```
{
    "python_virtualenv_paths": [
        "path-to-your-newly-created-virtualenv",
    ],
}
```

Comment: SublimeREPL is a plugin for ST that provides a REPL environment for various languages. It's not the same as using the bundled version of Python from the console (which, anyways, on ST2 is 2.6.x)